# How do you remove a bookmark from the LEd editor?

Tags: bookmarks, led-editor

I have introduced a bookmark by mistake into the LEd editor but can't seem to remove it. I can of course add a bookmark by using Ctrl+B and reference the location by Ctrl+No., but there seems no obvious way of removing one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does pressing `Ctrl+B` again solve your problem?

Comment: By uninstalling LEd for example. That would help more. It was amazing but it's really old and buggy.